# how to combine two json array with object.assign

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to combine these two json arrays :

```
mk = [ { sender: 'supporter',
    title: 'test4567',
    description: 'test',
    time: 1550387162726,


 image:
     'http://185.94.99.69:9000/upload/ticket/image/5c6907da43cbef2d3ce4b653/1550387163125.png' } ]
ticket.msg = [ { sender: 'supporter',
    title: 'test4567',
    description: 'test',
    time: 1550387162726,
    _id: 5c6907da43cbef2d3ce4b652,
    image: '' } ]
```

I have done this using Object.assign :

```
 newMsg = Object.assign([], mk,ticket.msg)
```

but it does not do it right.this is the result :

```
[ { sender: 'supporter',
    title: 'test4567',
    description: 'test',
    time: 1550387162726,
    _id: 5c6907da43cbef2d3ce4b652,
    image: '' } ]
```

i except it to be :

```
[ { sender: 'supporter',
    title: 'test4567',
    description: 'test',
    time: 1550387162726,
    _id: 5c6907da43cbef2d3ce4b652,
    image: 'http://185.94.99.69:9000/upload/ticket/image/5c6907da43cbef2d3ce4b653/1550387163125.png' } ]
```

Comment: So you expect that the `img` value with "http:" is more important than the `img` with value ""? Could you elaborate what your rules are for the merge? The largest string survives?

Comment: Array `mk` and `ticket.msg` will always have 1 object inside them?

Comment: I want to update this object in mongodb.I have to merge last value(ticket.msg) and the new value(mk) to have it all. @trincot

Comment: This does not answer the comments, really. Could you please address them? Do you mean that what is in `mk` should have priority over what is in `ticket.msg`? In that case you put them in the wrong order in `Object.assign`, and you should merge the element of the array, not the array.

Comment: @Prasun no,they can have more objects.

Comment: If they have more objects, then on what basis should the merge happen? What is the key? This question really needs more information *inside* it...

Answer (score 0):

Using Object.assign()

```js
var mk = [{
    sender: 'supporter',
    title: 'test4567',
    description: 'test',
    time: 1550387162726,
    image: 'http://185.94.99.69:9000/upload/ticket/image/5c6907da43cbef2d3ce4b653/1550387163125.png'
  }]
  var ticket_msg = [{
    sender: 'supporter',
    title: 'test4567',
    description: 'test',
    time: 1550387162726,
    _id: '5c6907da43cbef2d3ce4b652',
    image: ''
  }]
 var a=Object.assign({},ticket_msg[0],mk[0]);
 console.log(a)
```

You can also use the spread operator

```js
var mk = [{
    sender: 'supporter',
    title: 'test4567',
    description: 'test',
    time: 1550387162726,
    image: 'http://185.94.99.69:9000/upload/ticket/image/5c6907da43cbef2d3ce4b653/1550387163125.png'
  }]
  var ticket_msg = [{
    sender: 'supporter',
    title: 'test4567',
    description: 'test',
    time: 1550387162726,
    _id: '5c6907da43cbef2d3ce4b652',
    image: ''
  }]
 console.log([{...ticket_msg[0],...mk[0]}])
```

Comment: in your example _id is missing

Comment: [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Description) "assigns properties versus just copying or defining new properties. This may make it unsuitable for merging new properties into a prototype if the merge sources contain getters. For copying property definitions, including their enumerability, into prototypes `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor()` and `Object.defineProperty()` should be used instead."